# How to pass data to json from Database in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, eloquent

Here is my Row Query to get the data from database.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
```

I want to pass my $users array data to json format. How can I do so?

I have tried using Eloquent Model. but didn't work.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Um, did you try `json_encode`?

Comment: yes... I have tried. i m getting whole array values of database in json_encode(). Thank you..

Comment: @Jeff Puckett , I can use Eloquent Model to get data in JSON Object `return json_encode(User:all()); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Eloquent then you can use
->toJson();

But you are using Query builder. So you have to use php function:
json_encode()

For more information see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Yes  i m using Query Builder. Thanks

Comment: Bhavin, if my answer is helpful then please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent has a method named

```
->toJson()
```

However you're code doesn't looks like Eloquent.

Comment: I m using Query Builder. so using json_encode() , i can get array values in json format.

Answer (score 0):

To get an array instead of object, you have to pass true as second parameter

json_decode($user,true)